# Incorrect GestureDetector arguments. Having both a pan gesture recognizer and a scale gesture recognizer is redundant; scale is a superset of pan

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building CanvasTouchDetector(dirty, state: _CanvasTouchDetectorState#84c03):
Incorrect GestureDetector arguments.

Having both a pan gesture recognizer and a scale gesture recognizer is redundant; scale is a superset of pan.

Just use the scale gesture recognizer.

```
I found a solution as follow:

add
```

gesturesToOverride: [GestureType.onTapDown],

```
on CanvasTouchDetector
```

CanvasTouchDetector(
gesturesToOverride: [GestureType.onTapDown],
builder: (context) => .......

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.